# Can't use smbpasswd in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, passwords, samba, setup

When I try to run smbpasswd this is what I get:

```
cli_pipe_validate_current_pdu: RPC fault code DCERPC_FAULT_OP_RNG_ERROR received from host 127.0.0.1!
machine 127.0.0.1 rejected the password change: Error was : NT code 0x1c010002.
```

I'm using samba4. To use smbpasswd I just typed "smbpasswd" and pressed enter. There are no other machines involved. I have virtual machines in my system which I am trying to get to accesss files on this computer, but I don't think that counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if potential viewers of this request knew:

Which version of samba are you using?
What command did you give it that generated this error message?
Is there more than one machine involved?

Added:
You might initially at least need to execute smbpasswd as root, but I usually do this as follows:

```
$ sudo sh
```

(switch to superuser shell)

```
# smbpasswd -a username_one
```

(smbpasswd will prompt for password for user one)

```
# smbpasswd -a username_two
```

(smbpasswd will prompt for password for user two)

```
# exit
```

(superuser shell exits)

Once the smbpassword file is set up and populated then you can let regular users change their password

```
$ smbpasswd
```

(smbpassword prompts for old password, then new password)

Comment: The question has been updated to address these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing as root:

```
$ sudo smbpasswd
```

If that doesn't work, please post the contents of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`